# Nvidia-smi shows internal error after 11.2 Cuda installation on P2000 GPU

Tags: gpu, nvidia

I installed Cuda 11.2 on a Nvidia Quadro P2000 GPU. The driver version is R460 U5 (461.92). Unfortunately, after executing nvidia-smi, it shows me the following screen:

```
...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
Internal error
```

Does anyone know how to debug or fix this issue? nvidia-smi -v is not possible.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reinstalling the GPU driver and reinstalling CUDA solved the issue.